# How to set the default page and URL in RouteConfig file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my first time developing in MVC and have been stuck with this problem for a while now.

### What I want to do

I want to make the URL look like this:

```
example.com/SiteName/Project/Index/3
```

instead of this:

```
example.com/SiteName/Project?projectId=3
```

And also, I want users to be able to type `example.com/SiteName` and see `example.com/SiteName/Home/Index` because it's the default page.

### What I have

I have a page, **Home Page** which displays a list of projects. By clicking one of projects, **Project page** shows the details of the selected project.

In my `RouteConfig.cs` file, I have this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Project",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{proejctId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Index", projectId = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

### Problem

When I list the `routes.MapRoute` for `Project` first in the `RouteConfig.cs` file, I get the URL I want (`example.com/SiteName/Project/Index/3`).

However, when I try `example.com/SiteName`, it displays the `Error.cshtml` template in the Shared folder.

I found an SO question that mentioned that the order matters. 
But if I switch the order, `example.com/SiteName` does successfully display the `example.com/SiteName/Home/Index` page, but when I click a project in the list, the URL changes to this: `example.com/SiteName/Project?projectId=3`

How can I set the default page to Home/Index and still keep the URL as `example.com/SiteName/Project/3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routes to

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Project",
  url: "Project/{action}/{projectId}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Index", projectId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried but the default page is still redirected to the error page.

Comment: What is `SiteName`? Are you using areas? Why perpend it to the route?

Comment: `SiteName` is the application name. We have many independent applications under the `xxx.com` server.

Comment: OK, need to remove "SiteName/" from the route definitions (answer updated)